# What is the correct configuration to override primefaces messages.properties labels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, war, properties-file

I'm trying to override `PrimeFaces` `messages.properties` labels in my messages without success.

This is what I'm trying to do to change datatable labels:

1. This is my `faces-config.xml`:

   ```
   <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
   version="2.2">

   <application>

       <locale-config>
           <default-locale>it</default-locale>
           <supported-locale>it</supported-locale>
           <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
       </locale-config>

       <resource-bundle>
           <base-name>i18n.messages</base-name>
           <var>msg</var>
       </resource-bundle>
       <resource-bundle>
           <base-name>i18n.primefaces</base-name>
           <var>messages</var>
       </resource-bundle>

   </application>


   </faces-config>
   ```
2. `resources/i18n/messages.properties` contains my own application labels (`app`), and in `resources/i18n/primefaces.properties` I would like to put just primefaces override of this [Messages.properties](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b1d7673fecf7e8f44008bf1580982590a5fbc3aa/src/main/resources/org/primefaces/Messages.properties).
3. So in `resources/i18n/primefaces.properties` file I have this content:

   ```
   primefaces.datatable.SORT_ASC = Ascending
   primefaces.datatable.SORT_DESC = Descending
   ```
4. And in `resources/i18n/primeface_it.properties` file I have this content:

   ```
   primefaces.datatable.SORT_ASC = Crescente
   primefaces.datatable.SORT_DESC = Decrescente
   ```
5. Nothing happens, even if I switched to Italian locale I continue to see English translations for `SORT_ASC` and `SORT_DESC` labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'basename' for the PrimeFaces properties is 'org.primefaces.Messages', so to add a translation for it, you need to put a `Messages_it.properties` in `resources/org/primefaces` in your project. If you also want to override the default PF ones, put a `Messages.properties` in there as well (make sure it contains a copy of each key and override the values).

And you do not need to override or add the resource-bundle in your faces-config since these are already defined in the faces-config that is in the PrimeFaces jar.